# Where to store a large amount of media files in a Node.js eco-system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, storage, hosting

Long time lurker first time poster. Hi.

I've got a Node.js backend server, serving React.js in the front end. I'm uploading a huge amount of mp3 and wav files to the server itself currently. That is, a user uploads a file in my front end, and I create a folder on the server the node instance is running on and store the mp3/wav there, pertaining to that user.

The project is moving out of development into production, and I'm wondering from a scalability perspective a) how bad is this practice b) what my best options are for hosting, and c) alternative options to storing files on the server itself.

There is an existing user base of about 500 users, each of which uploads about 600MB - 1.5GB of media every 1.5 months.

Any insight would be great, as search seems inconclusive. Thanks!

Comment: Some options for storage.  1) Local hard drives, 2) LAN hard drives, 3) Cloud storage (like AWS), 4) NAS (network attached storage).  What to use depends entirely upon a detailed understanding of needs, access patterns, total storage, etc... which you have not provided.  In general, start simple with locally attached hard drives and only go more complex when demand or needs drive you to something more capable.

Comment: FYI, if your numbers are right, you're looking at adding 500GB/month of uploads.  If you have to keep all those uploads indefinitely, then you will need 6TB for the first year (assuming no unplanned user growth). I think I'd be looking into cloud storage unless you want to be in the business of managing a bunch of hard drives and virtualizing them and maintaining them and backing them up and adding redundancy.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) - The files need to be streamed. In short I'm building a service where users can upload music files, and others can stream them, so access will be exponentially more than num users. I will look into AWS as this seems like the most simple approach. Thank you!

Comment: @rpierre I recently worked on rebuilding Radio Reddit.  There's a full music server API for handling uploads, transcoding, etc., all built around AWS.  The code was intended to be open source, but I left the project before it was opened up.  I can get you in touch with those folks if you'd like.  E-mail me at brad@audiopump.co.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you integrate with CDN cloud servers. e.g **dropbox**,google, or AWS .  its has very flexible API including role based access, and authentication.

Even if you want to keep on your server, I suggest  to run separate server only to upload/download files and create oauth based authentication, system.

In case you also want to go for streaming. Then also there are cloud server which offer streaming support like wows,airplayit etc.